# Creating grid view with clickable images in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

I want to create a grid view with clickable images.

Whenever an image is clicked, a corresponding value will be shown below that grid view.

[image: Design of that grid view should be something like this]

The problem I am facing is in the design part, I don't know how to design a grid view like this. Every time I try to do that I get some bad results. I have no android UI design experience as of now.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Refer this links  http://mytelcoit.com/2010/02/programming-android-create-icon-with-text-using-gridview-and-layout-inflater/   http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/09/custom-gridview-ii-with-imageview-and.html

Comment: I hope it may help you http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Comment: Some other useful resources: [`AdapterViews`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews), [Mykong GridView example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) and [`GridView` documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Answer (score 3):

## Try this

1. Main activity

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<String> list;
      int[] imageId = {
       R.drawable.a,
       R.drawable.b,
       R.drawable.c,
       R.drawable.d,
       R.drawable.e,
       R.drawable.f,
        };
         String[] web = {
       "Google",
       "Github",
       "Instagram",
       "Facebook",
       "Flickr",
       "Pinterest",
       "Quora",
       "Twitter",
       "Vimeo",
       "WordPress",
       "Youtube",
       "Stumbleupon",
       "SoundCloud",
       "Reddit",
       "Blogger"

       } ;
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this,web, 
      imageId);
       GridView grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
      grid.setAdapter(adapter);
     grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int position, long id) {
       }
   });

    }
    }
   ```

   1. activity_main

      ```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context="com.example.mypc.grid.MainActivity">

       <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
           android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
      android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
        </GridView>
        </LinearLayout>
      ```
   2. ImageAdapter class

      ```
      public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
      {
       private Context mContext;
       private final int[] Imageid;
       private final String[] web;
          public ImageAdapter(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid )
        {
         mContext = c;
         this.Imageid = Imageid;
           this.web=web;
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount()
      {
           return Imageid.length;
       }
      @Override
       public Object getItem(int position)
      {
           return position;
        }
        @Override
       public long getItemId(int position)
      {
          return 0;
         }
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
         parent)
        {
           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View gridView;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
               gridView = new View(mContext);
               // get layout from mobile.xml
               gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null);
              // set value into textview
              TextView textView = (TextView) 
              gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
              textView.setText(web[position]);
             // set image based on selected text
             ImageView imageView = (ImageView) 
             gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
             imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
         }
         else
       {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
       }
          return gridView;
       }
      }
      ```
   3. grid_layout

      ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        >
       </ImageView>
       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@+id/label"
          android:layout_marginTop="5px"
          android:textSize="15px" >
         </TextView>

         </LinearLayout>
      ```