# Is this correct way to make design layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I've started today with Android programming, so, as a beginner, i'm curious is there any better and more appropriate way to make this layout than i've made with my XML code.
I need to have two containers that hold some picture and text that stands below that picture (see image below), each.

[image: layout]

XML:

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="140dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:baselineAligned="false"
   >

 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="#024f50"> 

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/doktor"
        android:contentDescription="@string/doktor"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/doktor"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:textColor="@color/box_text"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="#024f50"> 

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sestra"
        android:contentDescription="@string/sestra"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/sestra"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:textColor="@color/box_text"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you must use gridview if your items' count more than 2 or is dynamic. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947452/creating-gridview-having-clickable-images-android)

Comment: Try asking on http://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Use

> android:drawableTop=""

in TextView for adding image.

> ```
>         <TextView
>             android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_drawable"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>             android:text="@string/doktor"
>             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>             android:textColor="@color/box_text"/>
> ```